# Prevent duplicate child entries while saving parent entity in spring boot spring data jpa involving multiple thread access

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a spring boot application where we are trying to save information related to notifications received from third-party systems. The information is saved only when there exists a subscription for a specific kind of notification.

In short, we have three different entities present. 
1) A subscription entity which is a combination of 
  a) a subscriber or User
  b) a subject on which the subscription is taken
  c) type of notification on which a subscriber took the subscription with respect to a subject.

2) A subscriber entity

3) a subject entity

While implementing a save subscription scenario in spring data jpa we are facing an issue related to the duplication of data.

The way the functionality is envisioned we get the information related to both subject, subscriber, and type as part of the notification subscription post message.

```
{
"notificationTypeCodes" : [""],
"subjectId" : "Person1",
"subscriberId" : "USER1"
```

}

we then save this information in three different tables 1) subscription table
2) subjectId 3) subscriberId

The subscription table contains the relationship columns containing combination of id wrt ( notificationTypeCodes,subjectId,subscriberId).
The data wrt these ids are placed in their respective tables.

we are populating all three tables in the same transaction using the cascading approach. In order to prevent duplicate values being entered in any of the tables, we tried doing a getsubscritopn before save and set up a condition statement stating that it subscription does not exist them only save the subscription

subscription object = fetchsubscription();

if(subscription is not present)
{
save subscritopm)
}
else{
response stating subscritpion exists
}

But in case of multithreading scenarios, our check is falling as multiple threads are entering the if block before the subscription is saved and duplicate entries are getting crated in all three tables.

we cannot create constraints on a table as we can have scenarios where

different users(subscribers) can subscribe on same subjects and if we have constraints on a subject table this valid scenario might be rolled back.

Is there a way that we can handle the duplicate scenario the DB level. where we can throw a unique constraint exception. if we are storing a duplicate subscription.

Note: we don't have any constraints on the table as of now.
2) we don't want to use synchronized block in the service class

It would be great if someone can provide some insite into the same.
Thanks
in advance

I have now tried to explain the same problem with books publisher and bookspublisher entity

**************** bookspublisher entity************
    package com.hellokoding.jpa.model;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book_publisher")
public class BookPublisher
{


    @Id
    private int id;

    public BookPublisher() {

    }
    public Book getBook()
    {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook( Book aBook )
    {
        book = aBook;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( int aId )
    {
        id = aId;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher()
    {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher( Publisher aPublisher )
    {
        publisher = aPublisher;
    }


    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    private Publisher publisher;


}
```

Service to persists bookspublisher data.

The issue is when I am persisting the BookPublisher entity in multithreading environment duplicate data is getting created in both books and publisher tables.

The use case states that only the very first time when a new book or publisher comes it should be persisted in rest of the calls no duplicate entries should be allowed in the tables.

@Service
public class BookPublisherService
{

```
@Autowired
private BookPublisherRepository bookpublisherRepository;




@Transactional
public void saveSubscription( BookPublisherRequest aRequest )
{
    String bookName= aRequest.getBook();
    String publisher= aRequest.getPublisher();
    BookPublisher subscription = new BookPublisher();
    subscription.setBook( new Book( bookName) );
    subscription.setPublisher( new Publisher( publisher ) );
    bookpublisherRepository.save( subscription );

}
```

}

**Is it possible that if book and publisher values already exists then the same id's are provided to the publisherbook entity and by having unique constrain on that single table(publisherbook ) i can throw publishbook already exists message.**

Answer (score 0):

These two statements seem contradictory:

> we cannot create constraints on a table as we can have scenarios where
>   different users(subscribers) can subscribe on same subjects and if we have constraints on a subject table this valid scenario might be rolled back.

and

> Is there a way that we can handle the duplicate scenario the DB level. where we can throw a unique constraint exception. if we are storing a duplicate subscription.

It sounds like you need a unique constraint on your Subscription entity to prevent the duplicates.  i.e.

```
@Table(name = "subscriptions", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_sub", columnNames = {"notificationTypeCode", "subscriberId", "subjectId"}))
```

Comment: Thanks joe for your reply but in our case the subscriber id , subject id are persisted first . And the ids generated are then persisted in the subscription table. And since there are no constraints on the subject id and subscriber table the records are presisted with new ids and the unique contains dfoes not hold any good for sunscription table.

Comment: sry for the confusion I meant if we could throw some exception stating that that subscription already exists.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar use case and solved it as following, maybe that helps: a) put appropriate unique constraint on DB, b) before persist, search if record already exists, c) try to persist (fails with DB exception), d) if persisting failed, search another time (record is persisted now by yourself or another thread), e) use record as needed

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding what you mean.  Can you share the code that encapsulates your transaction?

Comment: I understand what you're saying now.  I believe the appropriate approach would be to set the unique constraints on the Subscriber and Subject tables such that they disallow duplicates.  Configure retry on your transactional method to retry this specific case 2 times (one for constraint violation on Subscriber, one for Subject).  For example:


    @Retryable(value = DataAccessException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(5000))